# Pass parameters from delphi to a bat file and from bat to php

Tags: php, delphi, batch-file, cmd

I use the code below to pass these three parameters from delphi to the bat file:

```
CommandLine := Format('cmd.exe /c "d:\run.bat %s"', [Email, StartDate, EndDate]);
```

The run.bat file itself contains:

```
@echo off
cls
D:
cd \test
"C:\PHP\php.exe" index.php %3
```

What I am trying to do is to call a bat file from Delphi and pass three parameters. The bat file itself executes a php file to which I need to pass this three parameters and access them via `$argv`. Using this code I am not able to do this. Can you help me to point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I only see one %s in your formatstring?

Comment: @fvu I am not sure if that %s if useful to be honest

Comment: How else would you pass the parameters to the batchfile? What's more, you only pass the third parameter to the php file, which is at least suspicious

Comment: @fvu it used to work to transfer only one variable

Comment: @fvu this are the parameters: [Email, StartDate, EndDate]

Comment: @fvu ah well, I want to pass all three parameters. I thought %3 means pass three parameters :/

Comment: You need to understand how `Format` works. Your code is clearly mis-using it. You've provided three parameters, but only defined one of them in the string, as previously mentioned. The same mistake was repeated inside the Batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass around three parameters, they should all appear on both the producing and the consuming side, like this:

```
CommandLine := Format('cmd.exe /c "d:\run.bat %s %s %s"', [Email, StartDate, EndDate]);
```

(assuming that StartDate and EndDate are strings, adapt accordingly if needed) and in the batchfile

```
@echo off
cls
D:
cd \test
"C:\PHP\php.exe" index.php %1 %2 %3
```

Where %1 means "the first command line parameter", %2 "the second", and so on.

Comment: I sort of expected that, that's exactly why I said `assuming that StartDate and EndDate are strings, adapt accordingly if needed`. If they're TDateTimes, check out FormatDateTime

Comment: @ZenAM What types are `StartDate` and `EndDate`? If they are `TDateTime`, you will first need to convert them to a valid string which PHP will understand.